# Is there an umbrella term for syntax elements that open and close, like parentheses?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I think we're all familiar with the concept of syntactic elements that are opened and closed, and can be nested in some cases.

Examples:

- (), [], {}, <> et. al.
- Parenthetic clauses, such as this one, which fall within a sentence
- Quotation marks: "a direct quote" and 'another'

Programmers will also be familiar with examples from formal languages such as HTML tags: `<p> This is a paragraph element </p>`. Indentation often also often manifests this concept in programming languages.

There are also more abstract examples such as adverts on television that are split into two parts, and "frame" a portion of content (for example part 1 asks a question, part 2 answers it later).

Is there a name for this? "Parenthesis" covers a lot of it, but it doesn't really include quotation marks, nested formal language constructs (like HTML tags), or totally abstract examples like TV ads. Also, the "parenthesis" in a parenthetic clause refers to the *contained* element ("such as this one"), not the *containing* element ("Parenthetic clauses ... which fall within a sentence").

Comment: Not a term of art but... "enclosing elements" or an "enclosing pair"?

(However, by that reckoning that which is contained would be an "enclosure," which might sound too much like a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) for your liking.)

See also [bookend](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bookend), "one of two usually similar things that begin and end something" - a rather lovely word.

Answer (score 3):

"Brackets" can be used as a generic term to cover parentheses (), angle brackets <>, square brackets [], curly brackets {} etc.

The term for a character that marks the beginning and end of a sequence of characters is a *delimiter*. This would include HTML tags and the like.

Comment: In CSV files, commas are delimiters even though they only come between data sequences.  So even if the things the question asks about are one kind of delimiter, [I]delimiter[/I] doesn't only refer to what he's asking about. And of course the quotation marks he mentioned aren't usually considered brackets.